# AWS Cognito - Prevent users from changing their password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm working on AWS Cognito, and I want to prevent users from changing their password. Can I do it with Cognito? I try to set group's role for those users, but nothing happened! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I can think of is if you have an application that has a client secret and you don't expose password change APIs in your application. Users won't be able to authenticate outside your application because they don't have the client secret and won't be able to use the forgotPassword API since that requires the secretHash that is computed from the client secret.